# The author allows me to use their (excellent) idea, but I need to paraphrase it. I can't find a good paraphrase. What should I do?

Tags: copyright, quotes

I meet an excellent idea and really want to use it. The author allows me to do that, but I can't just copy the whole text. The problem is, I do want to use my own language, but in each sentence they have organized keywords in perfect combination, making it much concrete and enlightening, and I really don't know how to put it in another way. It's like a perfect quote or essay from a book that you just can't add or remove any word (or such modification can't be substantial). What should I do?

Comment: Why not just cite it?

Comment: They don't want either

Comment: I'm not sure they can stop you citing it, as long as you reference it correctly. But if you don't want to do that I don't have an answer, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrase it as best you can.

Else just cite it.  Permitted as fair use and what the original author wants is irrelevant.

Caveat:  If you are talking about using pages of text then that may not be fair use.
If you are talking about a paragraph then that should be okay.

Comment: yeah, I paraphrase it as best as I can, but their original wording is still obvious. It's actually a couple of their paragraphes in various places in our conversations (publicly on Reddit). Why would what they want is irrelevant?

Comment: @Ooker Because if you want to cite it (and give them the proper credit), then I don't think they can stop you. Of course, if they're your friend and you want to keep it that way, then it might still count as 'relevant' to your friendship.